# How to code for moving/removing an mvc route "forever"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, redirect, seo

I have a few pages on a website that have recently been moved (to another mvc route) and some have been removed.  How should such a change be handled, in terms of being nice to search engines (and my users)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the URL rewrite module in IIS to issue 301/302 redirects for those faulty/moved routes.  This will make Google/Bing happy for your SEO and keeps any bookmarked links from going dead.

Since you didn't provide any examples, I can't show you how to really use the rewrite for your case, but [learn.iis.net](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/664/using-url-rewrite-module-20/) has a ton of data/examples/use cases.

A simple/silly example.  We are going to redirect from the blog controller to the article controller (in your web.config)

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect from blog">
      <match url="^blog/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="article/{R:2}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Ben's solution at:

http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/aspnet-mvc-issuing-multiple-301-redirects

It looks to be an approach you may find useful.